# Kubernetes. ASP.NET containers with Wix installer

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, wix, containers

**What I have:**
Application based on near 10 microservices created with `ASP.NET Core`. One of them is Web server. `Wix installer` is used to create Windows installer.

**What is required:**
Migrate application to `Kubernetes` so all benefits in form of Scalability, load balancing, self healing would be present.

**Complications:**
`Kubernetes` does not run on Windows containers in `Windows Professional`. As an alternative - `Windows server`, but technology is raw, without much docs and complicates running on dev machines.
As an alternative - setup `Linux` environment, but in this case `Wix installer` may not work or requires major changes.

So how such `ASP.NET` microservices app with `Wix installer` can be run on `Kubernetes`?